# Is there a way to slightly shrink a table, including font size, to fit within the column boundaries?

Tags: tables, scaling

I have a table that is just a little too wide for a 3.33" column. Is there a way to simply shrink the table a little to make it fit? I'm OK if the 10pt font becomes 9pt-something. Here is an example.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{r|lll}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 1}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 2}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 3} \\ \cline{2-4}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Why not just use `\small` or `\footnotesize` at the beginning of `table` environment? Box scaling also has disadvantage, tabular line will be slightly scaled.

Comment: it make more sense to scale it exactly to linewidth, which is the same as using the best font size!

Comment: @Herbert, it is not quite the same as using the best font size, due to optical scaling of the fonts. Ie, cmr10 at 90% scale is not the same as cmr9. Also, as Leo says, the weight of the tabular lines will not be completely consistent.

Comment: I just tried `\small` after `\begin{table}`, and although it does the job, I like the output that `\resizebox` gives better.

Comment: @Lev: as I said, scaling is better than using a too small font size. And the line width will also be scaled down so that they are still proportional to the font.

Comment: @Herbert, yes the linewidth will be scaled down. This means that with two tables on the same page, one will have heavier lines than the other, which can look unpleasant. I agree that using too-small font is bad, but rescaling is not quite the same thing as using the best font size. (Although for a very slight rescaling as in this case it should still look fine).

Comment: @Lev: we were talking of _one_ table and I gave a solution for this case. If I have another situation I'll give another solutions ...

Answer (score 292, accepted):

You can resize it using `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}` from the `graphics` package. The column width is `\columnwidth` and you can select `!` for the height to make it scale along with the width.

```
\usepackage{graphics}
% ...

\begin{table}
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{r|lll}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 1}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 2}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 3} \\ \cline{2-4}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

Should the table include verbatim or similar material than `\resizebox` isn't good enough. You can use the `{adjustbox}{width=\columnwidth}` environment from the `adjustbox` package instead. It is based on the same `graphicx` code as `\resizebox` but allows for any content.

Please do not use the `center` environment in floats (`figure`, `table`), it generates an extra margin and doesn't always work. Use the `\centering` macro instead.

---

Solution with `adjustbox`:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
% ...
\begin{table}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\columnwidth,center}
\begin{tabular}{r|lll}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 1}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 2}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 3} \\ \cline{2-4}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I have changed the question (and my paper) to use the \centering macro, thanks.

Comment: This worked the best for me. Using either `\columnwidth` or `\linewidth` seemed to give exactly the same results.

Comment: @Nathan: Please note that `\columnwidth` should always be the width of the column. The `\linewidth` is the width of the text lines and is different depending if you are in single of double column mode.

Comment: @Martin: that is not correct. They have both the same value, `\textwidth` is the width of the onecolumn part

Comment: Thanks @Herbert. So `\linewidth`=`\textwidth` for one-column texts, but `\linewidth`=`\columnwidth` for two (or more) columns, isn't it?

Comment: @Martin: `\columnwidth` is correct for twocolumn mode, but `\linewidth` is the width of the _current line_, which can be smaller than `\columnwidth`, eg in a quotation environment in twocolumn mode which sets its own margins.

Comment: @Nathan: See now also the answers to my question [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize), if you are interested.

Comment: `\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{}` works.

Answer (score 89):

You can scale the whole table using `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.9}{
\begin{tabular}{r|lll}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 1}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 2}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 3} \\ \cline{2-4}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3
\end{tabular}}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used `\scalebox` for years until I figured out that there is `\resizebox`! :-) You miss a `%` behind it.

Comment: I have now tried both `\scalebox` and `\resizebox`, and I like `\resizebox` better because it seems to give a better end result.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Why do you say that? I don't understand that comment.

Answer (score 38):

you can resize it to exactly the linewidth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill

\smallskip\noindent
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{r|lll}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 1}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 2}
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{Heading 3} \\ \cline{2-4}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the `\noindent` is really neat when equation numbering are in the picture!

Answer (score 7):

If the tabular only needs to scaled down very little, it might be worth trying out the `widetable` package which is like a `tabular*` but does not need `\extracolsep` and works by calculating the right value for `\tabcolsep`, i.e, stretching or shrinking the intercolumn space on either side of a vertical line (if the table has them). This way the fontsize will stay the same which may be an advantage. But of course the maximum shrink is to zero (and that is seldom a workable idea) so it only works if the amount is needed small and the table has many columns.

Answer (score 5):

This is a visual comparison to show that just scale too wide tables (right column) is *always* the wrong approach. The solution should be reducing the font size, and the column separations if needed, and  in case it is necessary also to fit the width of the table exactly, use `tabular*` environment or packages as tabularx, tabulary or widetable (left column), and when nothing is enough, redesign the table (not showed).

[image: mwe]

Do you see the problems at the right? Let me explain:

1. The rules are also scaled, giving inconsistent thin rules (ugly, right?).
2. The text of normal size scaled down do not look like small fonts (obtained with `\small`, `\footnotesize`, `\scriptize` or `\tiny`). It is less readable.
3. Worse, every scaled table will have a different font size: 40 tables = 40 font sizes, not  2 or 3 standard sizes through the whole document (very ugly, right?).
4. Worse, as you can scale down infinitely the table, the risk of allowing ridiculously unreadable small fonts sizes is high. Maybe you have noticed the that the last header if the left-bottom table have the wrong number, but...  have you noticed that there are also four badly numbered cells in last table of the right column?

With the other approach, you decide the limit (note: the mine is `\footnotesize`) or if you lack common sense you cannot low to absurd limits. It is important to have that limit, because it will tell you when you have to pass plan B (redesign the table).

The code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip,booktabs,graphicx,tabulary,tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,bmargin=7cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

 \lipsum[1][1-3]    

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXX}\toprule
& Heading 1 & Heading 2\\\cmidrule{2-3}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

% \lipsum[2][1-3]   

{\small\tabcolsep5pt 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lXXX@{}}\toprule
& Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3 \\\cmidrule{2-4}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}

{\scriptsize
\tabcolsep1.7pt 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lXXXX@{}}\toprule
& Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3 & Heading 4 \\\cmidrule{2-5}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 & Cell 1,4 \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3 & Cell 2,4 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}


{\tiny
\tabcolsep1.1pt 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lXXXXX@{}}\toprule
& Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3 & Heading 4 & Heading 5\\\cmidrule{2-6}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 & Cell 1,4 & Cell 1,5   \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3 & Cell 2,4 & Cell 2,5 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}


{\tiny\tabcolsep1pt
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}lCCCCCCC@{}}\toprule
& Heading 1 &  Heading 2 & Heading 3 &  Heading 4 &  Heading 5 & Heading 6\\\cmidrule{2-7}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 & Cell 1,4 & Cell 1,5  & Cell 1,5 \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3 & Cell 2,4 & Cell 2,5  & Cell 1,5 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}}


{\tiny\tabcolsep1pt
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}lCCCCCCCC@{}}\toprule
& Heading 1 &  Heading 2 & Heading 3 &  Heading 4 &  Heading 5 & Heading 6 & Heading 6\\\cmidrule{2-8}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 & Cell 1,4 & Cell 1,5  & Cell 1,6  & Cell 1,7  \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3 & Cell 2,4 & Cell 2,5  & Cell 2,5  & Cell 2,7  \\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}}

\lipsum[2][1]
\footnote{Footnote as reference of reasonable and standard small font.} 

    \newpage \lipsum[1][1-3]    


{\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
& Heading 1 & Heading 2\\\cmidrule{2-3}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\par}

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{llll}\toprule
& Heading 1
& Heading 2
& Heading 3 \\\cmidrule{2-4}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lllll}\toprule
 & Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3 & Heading 4 \\\cmidrule{2-5}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 & Cell 1,4 \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3 & Cell 2,4 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{llllll}\toprule
& Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3 & Heading 4 & Heading 5\\\cmidrule{2-6}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 & Cell 1,4 & Cell 1,5\\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3 & Cell 2,4 & Cell 2,5\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}\toprule
 & Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3 & Heading 4 & Heading 5 & Heading 6\\\cmidrule{2-7}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 & Cell 1,4 & Cell 1,5  & Cell 1,5 \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3 & Cell 2,4 & Cell 2,5  & Cell 1,5 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{llllllll}\toprule
 & Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3 & Heading 4 & Heading 5 & Heading 6 & Heading 7\\\cmidrule{2-8}
Row 1 & Cell 1,1 & Cell 1,2 & Cell 1,3 & Cell 1,4 & Cell 1,5  & Cell 1,5  & Cell 1,5 \\
Row 2 & Cell 2,1 & Cell 2,2 & Cell 2,3 & Cell 2,4 & Cell 2,5  & Cell 1,5 & Cell 1,5  \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\lipsum[2][1-2]
\
\end{document}
```