# Set horizontal width of matrix in amsmath

Tags: amsmath, matrices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to slightly shrink a table, including font size, to fit within the column boundaries?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10863/is-there-a-way-to-slightly-shrink-a-table-including-font-size-to-fit-within-th)

I have a 16x16 `pmatrix`.  How do i set the width so it doesn't overflow my column?  E.g. something like `[width = 0.9\columnwidth]`.

I do not want to have to manually adjust the spacing, which by the way, seems too wide to me anyway.

Comment: Since `pmatrix` uses `array`, the only way to *shrink* it to the desired width would be to scale the entire `pmatrix`.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: @Ferguzz: See @ PeterGrill's answer. The use of `!` for the "unknown" dimension maintains the aspect ratio of the resizing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `\resizebox` from [the `graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx). Here I have used the `[showframe]` option of [the `geometry` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) so that the column edges are visible:

[image]

If you don't want the matrix to use the full  line width you can use `{0.9\linewidth}` so that it re sizes to 90% of the line width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$\begin{pmatrix}
 Column1 & Column2 & Column3 & Column4 & Column5 & Column6 & Column7 & Column8 & Column9
\end{pmatrix}$

\noindent
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
$\begin{pmatrix}
 Column1 & Column2 & Column3 & Column4 & Column5 & Column6 & Column7 & Column8 & Column9
\end{pmatrix}$%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%` otherwise you'll get an unwanted space. Same before the closing `}`

Comment: thanks.  good answer and does what i need.  i am still intrigued as to how to set the default spacing for pmatrix. i will post here if i do find out.

Answer (score 10):

To set horizontal spacing in math arrays:  `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}`.

Default is 6pt.

Source: http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/squeeze.html

Comment: Even though this fixes the width between columns in an `array` (`pmatrix` is typeset in using an `array`) to `3pt`, which is less than the default `6pt`, does it really answer your question? Remember, in this Q&A format, the "Answer" section is devoted to answers.

Comment: yes this exactly the answer i was searching for. in the question what i meant by 'I do not want to have to manually adjust the spacing' was 'I do not want to have to manually adjust the spacing using \! for each entry.' perhaps i should have been more clear.

Comment: True. However, such things only become clear once you've examined the answers clearly. For `tabular` spacing and future reference, see [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-padding-in-tables).