# Equal matrix column width and draw vertical line

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, matrices

I want to write a matrix with equal column widths, plus have a vertical line down the matrix. By using the solutions given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39852/set-horizontal-width-of-matrix-in-amsmath) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253739/vertical-and-horizontal-line-in-a-matrix), I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% draw vertical line down matrix
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}[cc|cc]
 C1 & Column2 & C3 & C4 \\ \hline
 C5 & C6 & C7 & Column8
\end{pmatrix}$%
\end{equation}
}

\end{document}
```

The output matrix does not have equal column widths, and I get an error `Missing $ inserted`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `\resizebox` around the `equation` environment doesn't. You could box that up, but this would most likely destroy the effects of `\resizebox`

Comment: What do you mean to get with `\resizebox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Notes:**

1. The error `Missing $ inserted` is because of the single `$` sign at `\end{pmatrix}$%`.
2. You can use `\resizebox{.9\hsize}{!}{%` inside the equation (see [Scale an equation to fit exact page width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3106587/7440933)).
3. I used `tabularx` to define a new columntype `C`, witch allows you to set the width of a centered entry by using `C{<width>}`.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% draw vertical line down matrix
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \resizebox{.9\hsize}{!}{\ensuremath{
        \begin{pmatrix}[*2{C{15mm}}|*2{C{15mm}}]
            C1 & Column2 & C3 & C4 \\ \hline
            C5 & C6 & C7 & Column8
        \end{pmatrix}%
    }}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I should also add that the `$` notation is necessary for mathmode, e.g. `$\alpha$`.

Answer (score 1):

- in your *mwe* you have superfluous `$` on the end of `pmatrix`
- instead of hacked `pmatrix` i would rather use standard `array` environment (see difference at horizontal line)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% draw vertical line down matrix
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

your solution (corrected and without \verb+\resizebox+):
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}[cc|cc]
 C1 & Column2 & C3 & C4 \\ \hline
 C5 & C6 & C7 & Column8
\end{pmatrix}%
\end{equation}

with proposed use of \verb+array+:
\begin{equation}\setlength\arraycolsep{1.5pt}
\left(\begin{array}{C{4em}C{4em}|C{4em}C{4em}}
 C1 & Column2 & C3 & C4 \\ \hline
 C5 & C6 & C7 & Column8
\end{array}\right)%
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The environment `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` has a key `columns-width=auto` which specify that all the columns must have the same width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{pNiceArray}{cc|cc}[columns-width=auto,margin]
 C1 & Column2 & C3 & C4 \\ \hline
 C5 & C6 & C7 & Column8
\end{pNiceArray}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]