# Resize table and caption

Tags: tables, captions, scaling

I usually apply a `\scalebox` to resize things, but I always stumble upon the fact that I cannot simply include a `\caption{...}` in the `\scalebox`.

As an alternative to `\scalebox`, I [found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10863/is-there-a-way-to-slightly-shrink-a-table-including-font-size-to-fit-within-th) I may use `\resizebox`, but this macro also does not allow me to include `\caption{...}`'s.

Is there anyway to resize both the `tabular` and the table's `caption`?

Comment: Using `scalebox` in this way is going to lead to an inconsistent looking document. Changes to `captions` (size/font/colour, etc) can be made using the `caption` package

Comment: @cmhughes So, does it mean there's no applicable macro for this case? Something like `\scale_tabular_and_caption{...}` \= There's no much concern about the looking of this `\tabular + \caption` and the rest of the document; I just want to have them both resized.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is working example of resizing table together with caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \caption{Table caption}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
          \hline
          $t_0~(MeV\cdot fm^3 ) $ & $t_3~(MeV\cdot fm^6)$ & $v_0/\mu~(MeV\cdot fm)$ & $1/\mu~(fm)$\\
          \hline
          $$ -497.726 & $17270$ & $-166.924$ & $0.45979$\\
          \hline
        \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

FIXED: Example was edited. Thanks!

Comment: +1 it might be worth mentioning that the same approach works with other boxes too such as `vbox`, `parbox`, etc. You can also just use `\centering` rather than `\begin{centering}...\end{centering}`; finally- `table` captions should go *on top* :)

Comment: Why `figure`? Use `table` and the simple `\caption` command. There are spurious spaces: one after `\resizebox{.5\hsize}{` (and `\textwidth` would be better than `\hsize`), one after `\end{minipage}`.

Answer (score 2):

### How to scale/resize a table/tabular inside a minipage

This question is the first one to pop up when searching for: `latex scale table in minipage`. Likewise queries such as `rescale table in minipage` or `resize table in minipage` end up at this answer too.

I was personally also searching for this and couldn't find an answer **anywhere**. However, 
I've found the solution. Judging by the amount of views of this question, I guess it'll be extremely helpful to some people to post it here.

So to `resize`/`rescale` a table **inside** a minipage, do the following:

Include the [adjustbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}    % only if you want to add a caption to your table
```

Now you can rescale your `tabular` or `table` environment as follows:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}                          % minipage spans half the textwidth
\begin{center}
  \begin{adjustbox}{center, width=\columnwidth-10pt}        % can also use \linewidth or sth. else

      % your table ..                                       % put your table here

  \end{adjustbox}
  \captionof{table}{Your caption goes here}                 % add a caption if you want
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
```

Note that I've used the parameter `center` (to center the content). Somehow I still needed `\begin{center} .. \end{center}` to get everything properly aligned. Also note I used `width=\columnwidth-10pt` which scales both the *width* and *height* of the table simultaneously.

To use other scaling, simply use another `width=` for your adjustbox. This works just as normal `width` parameters.

Hope that helped some people out :)

You can find additional documentation of `adjustbox` here: [**adjustbox documentation**](http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox/adjustbox.pdf).

### Edit: A MWE

A *minimal working example* ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) would be the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}    % only if you want to add a caption to your table

\begin{document}
\noindent                                                   % remove any indentation
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}                          % minipage spans half the textwidth
    \begin{center}
        \begin{adjustbox}{center, width=\columnwidth-10pt}  % can also use \linewidth or sth. else

            \begin{tabular}{c | c}                          % little tabular example
                Column 1 & Column 2 \\
                \hline
                1 & 2
            \end{tabular}

        \end{adjustbox}
        \captionof{table}{Your caption goes here}           % add a caption if you want
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please augment your code snippets to create a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001).

Comment: Why are you using `\columnwidth` rather than `\linewidth` to scale the `adjustbox` environment? Why are you subtracting `10pt` from the width of the `minipage`? If you set the width of the `adjustbox` environment to `\linewidth`, there would be no need to employ a `center` environment and thus no need to deal with the (presumably unwanted) extra vertical whitespace that's inserted by the `center` environment.

Comment: @Mico: Because my application happens to be two minipages next to each other. Please edit yourself if you feel the need to improve. For me it worked perfectly with the `center` environment so I put it in to illustrate a working example for any use-case of the `minipage` environment. Not just for the case when you *don't* need to deal with white spaces.

Comment: @Mico: Done as requested.

Comment: It's your posting, so *you* should provide all information that's needed for people to understand the stylistic, layout, and other choices you made. Otherwise, one or more of the choices you make, implicitly or explicitly, risk coming across as being random and/or unmotivated. Two suggestions for improving your code: (i) if you're going to place two minipages side by side, you should preface the first one with `\noindent`; (ii) use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` to avoid the (presumably unwanted) extra whitespace generated by the `center` environment.

Comment: I get your point but IMO changing the code to display how to position two minipages next to each other is distracting from the little tip I'm trying to give: using `adjustbox` for rescaling within `minipage` environments. People should change the parameters to their own application. However, I will add some comments.

Comment: Incidentally, your code (as currently posted) does not perform any rescaling at all. The argument `center` needs to be removed from the `adjustbox` environment in order for the rescaling to happen.

Comment: For me, it works perfectly. Using `PdfLaTeX` compiler. Tested multiple times. Please [**take a look here**](https://www.overleaf.com/2169577qqqtsb).

Comment: I've edited your code on overleaf.com to remove the two `center` options. (I've also inserted an `\hrule` in each `minipage` to illustrate their widths.) I think you'll now see a rather different amount of scaling being applied.