# An error using of tablenotes in longtable

Tags: longtable, threeparttable

I am trying to compile a longtable with table notes, but I am getting an error with the codes below:

```
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{threeparttable}
   \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \toprule
 \midrule

some table

    \bottomrule
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
     TS: The time span of relevant measurement.
     No: The number of measurements, those are given for the ease to refer the measurement, therefore they are not the arrangement of the measurements.
 \end{tablenotes}
     \end{threeparttable}  
   \end{longtable}  
\end{landscape}
```

and the error is:

```
! You can't use `\prevdepth' in restricted horizontal mode.
\TPTdoTablenotes ->\par \prevdepth 
                                   \z@ \TPT@hsize \TPTnoteSettings \parinden...
l.231 \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
```

finally my preamble:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
```

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{threeparttable}
   \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \caption{Adsorption and desorption measurement characteristics of MFU4.Br-1 and MFU4.Br-2.} \label{tab:meacon} \\
   some table
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
     TS: The time span of relevant measurement.
     No: The number of measurements, those are given for the ease to refer the measurement, therefore they are not related with the arrangement of the measurements.
 \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
   \end{longtable}%
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a Minimal Working Example (MWE) which replicate the problem!

Comment: @JagathAR I added a mwe.

Answer (score 1):

The corrected code should be as given below:

```
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\begin{threeparttable}
   \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \caption{Adsorption and desorption measurement characteristics of MFU4.Br-1 and MFU4.Br-2.} \label{tab:meacon}\\
a & b&c&d&e&f&g\\
a & b&c&d&e&f&g\\
   \end{longtable}% The error corrected  here!!!
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
     TS: The time span of relevant measurement.
     No: The number of measurements, those are given for the ease to refer the measurement, therefore they are not related with the arrangement of the measurements.
 \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}}
\end{landscape}
```

The `longtable` was not closed before starting `tablenotes`. This caused the error.

**Note:** Edited the code with `\resizebox` command.

Comment: now I have different problem that the table takes two pages, and when I use footnote code is trying to fix it in one page  that does not fit.

Comment: You can use `\resizebox` to re-size the table. See this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94078/resize-table-and-caption. Please put the `\resizebox{}{!}{\begin{threeparttable}{...} ... \end{threeparttable}`.

Comment: Using resizebox gives: 
`Runaway definition?
->}\expandafter \def \expandafter \@tempc \expandafter {\string !}\ifx \ETC.
! File ended while scanning definition of \@tempb.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.170 \input ch2`

Comment: I've added `\resizebox` in the sample code above.

Comment: ok. I added \resizebox, but now I am getting following error `Runaway argument?
{\begin {threeparttable} \begin {longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \caption \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \Gscale@box@dd.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.170 \input ch2`

Comment: Can you post the erroneous code which contains resizebox to the bottom of your question or add a new question!