# Table in a resizebox out of bounds

Tags: tables, graphics

I'm trying to resize a table so that it will fit a page, following the instructions given in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94078/resize-table-and-caption). However, \centering doesn't seem to work, as shown by this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
      \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
          \caption{Inflation for April 2014}
        \begin{tabular}{l|rrrrrrrr}
          \hline
          1. FOOD AND NON ALCOHOLIC BEBERAGE&0.79\%&0.86\%&3.06\%&8.51\%&5.26\%&3.48\%&5.70\%&6.43\%\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The table starts way off to the right and part of it ends up outside the page. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: that's not quite the point; the real table has a few more columns, so text wrapping won't cut it. I actually need to use the entire text width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
```

is a slow way of doing nothing, you make a minipage that is textwidth wide and scale it to textwidth.

Scaling tables is evil but if you really want to then

```
    \begin{table}
      \caption{Inflation for April 2014}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{l|rrrrrrrr}
      \hline
      1. FOOD AND NON ALCOHOLIC BEBERAGE&0.79\%&0.86\%&3.06\%&8.51\%&5.26\%&3.48\%&5.70\%&6.43\%\\\hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \end{table}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: why is scaling tables evil? What yould you do instead?

Comment: @ailnlv: You can use `\resizebox` for some fine-tuning. But the table size has already been decreased by more than 35 % and you say, there are even more columns in the real-world table? What's the purpose of the table, if nobody can read it? There are other means, e.g. landscape orientation, line breaks in the first text column, smaller font (`\small`, not `\tiny`), redesign of the table/splitting the table in two or more tables, ...

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: thanks. I'd vote you up but I don't have the required reputation yet :(

Comment: @ailnlv I'd not scale text:-) latex documents have consistent font sizes \small \large etc, so you could use \small\begin{tabular}... or whatever works or you could change the first column to p{1cm} or whatever so it isn't so wide, you could (should) remove the `%` from every cell and put it in the column head. If you scale, fonts go to an arbitrary size, rules might go to less than a pixel wide (and are inconsistent with the rest of the document and the result is well, inconsistent.