# Can LaTeX pick up the size of font in table?

Tags: tables, fontsize

Can LaTeX pick up the size of font in table? I want to create the table with rigorous bounds and that LaTeX pick up the size of font by itself.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please be a bit more specific about what you mean by "size of font in a table": Is it the font size in effect when `\begin{table}` is encountered, when `\begin{tabular}` is encountered, or something else. Separately, please also provide more information as to what you mean by a "table with rigorous bounds".

Comment: `table` and `tabular` will use the current fontsize unless they are otherwise reset.  if your code still doesn't know what that is, you could set a known character in a box and measure the height/width of the box, making a decision based on that information.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way people implement this is to just scale the table

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{lll} ....\end{tabular}}
```

see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179174/1090) but as noted there resizing this way leads to inconsistent font sizes 9and rule widths) and it's normally better to choose a specific font size such as `\small` in advance.

Comment: I have a table with digits like -20,20%, but Latex writes this number on two rows. And it is looks awful. I use the \tiny font size.

Comment: @Vadim latex would not normally break `-20,20%` so if it is doing you have some definitions that allow it to do so. You have given us no clue about your input, _every_ question should have a complete small example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem. If you edited your question to have an example of the problem, someone could tell you the solution.