# scale box problem in table

Tags: tables, rotating, adjustbox, scalebox

i was working on a table which is rotated by 90 degrees. I don't know what i might have deleted, and I don't get an output anymore. I have an extra } to put somewhere, but wherever I put it, it does not produce my table..
could you please take a look? thank a lot in advance

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\scalebox{0.7}{%
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}
\hline
Variabla & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2003} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2008}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{2012} \\
\hline
  $X_{it}$  &  Ln shitje  &  Ln paga  & Ln kapital  &  Ln aktive  & Ln shitje  &   Ln paga  & Ln kapital & Ln aktive & Ln shitje  &  Ln paga &  Lnkcapital  &  Ln aktive \\
export      &       0.699***&       0.192***&       0.646***&       0.779***&       0.837***&       0.238***&       0.627***&       0.842***&       0.923***&       0.245***&       0.593***&       0.957***\\
R-squared   &       0.463   &       0.047   &       0.390   &       0.429   &       0.512   &       0.120   &       0.373   &       0.4
57   &       0.492   &       0.135   &       0.327   &       0.425   \\
N  &   24909   &   24881  &   24909   &   24903   &   29826   &   29778   &   29826 &   29818   &   27050   &   26995  &   27050  &   27042  \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{}\label{fig:}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Your code misses the closing bracket from the `scalebox`. Aditionally, you can not that easily put a caption command inside an `adjustbox` environment (See [Resize table and caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94078/134144)). In order to rotate a table and its caption, I would use the `sidewaystable` environment from the `rotating` package.

As shown in the following MWE, your table and its caption get rotated, but still are much too wide to fit on the page. Reducing the fontsize might work to fit the table onto the page, but depending on the documentclass, one would need an extremely tiny font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}
\hline
Variabla & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2003} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2008}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{2012} \\
\hline
  $X_{it}$  &  Ln shitje  &  Ln paga  & Ln kapital  &  Ln aktive  & Ln shitje  &   Ln paga  & Ln kapital & Ln aktive & Ln shitje  &  Ln paga &  Lnkcapital  &  Ln aktive \\
export      &       0.699***&       0.192***&       0.646***&       0.779***&       0.837***&       0.238***&       0.627***&       0.842***&       0.923***&       0.245***&       0.593***&       0.957***\\
R-squared   &       0.463   &       0.047   &       0.390   &       0.429   &       0.512   &       0.120   &       0.373   &       0.4
57   &       0.492   &       0.135   &       0.327   &       0.425   \\
N  &   24909   &   24881  &   24909   &   24903   &   29826   &   29778   &   29826 &   29818   &   27050   &   26995  &   27050  &   27042  \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{}\label{fig:}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

You might therefor consider to change the layout of your table to something like the following. In this example, I have split up the long rows in thirds and used horizontal rules from  the `booktabs` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2003}  \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
  $X_{it}$  &  Ln shitje  &  Ln paga  & Ln kapital  &  Ln aktive  \\
export      &       0.699***&       0.192***&       0.646***&       0.779*** \\
R-squared   &       0.463   &       0.047   &       0.390   &       0.429   \\
N  &   24909   &   24881  &   24909   &   24903  \\
 \midrule
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2008} \\
 \cmidrule{2-5}
  $X_{it}$  &  Ln shitje  &  Ln paga  & Ln kapital  &  Ln aktive \\
  export      &   0.837***&       0.238***&       0.627***&       0.842***\\
  R-squared   &    0.512   &       0.120   &       0.373   &       0.4 \\
  N  &   29826   &   29778   &   29826 &   29818   \\
  \midrule
   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2012} \\
  \cmidrule{2-5}
    $X_{it}$  & Ln shitje  &  Ln paga &  Lnkcapital  &  Ln aktive \\
export      &   0.923***&       0.245***&       0.593***&       0.957***\\
R-squared   &       0.492   &       0.135   &       0.327   &       0.425   \\
N    &   27050   &   26995  &   27050  &   27042  \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%

\caption{some caption}
\label{fig:}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest swapping rows and columns, and using the rules of `booktabs` to add some vertical padding to the rows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{rotating, float, booktabs, multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\hskip 6pt}l*{4}{c}}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Variabla}\\
\midrule
 & $X_\mathrm{it}$ & export & R-squared & N\\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{2003}} & Ln shitje & 0.699*** & 0.463 & 24909 \\
 & Ln paga & 0.192*** & 0.047 & 24881 \\
 & Ln kapital & 0.646*** & 0.390 & 24909 \\
 & Ln aktive & 0.779*** & 0.429 & 24903 \\
 \addlinespace
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{2008}} & Ln shitje & 0.837*** & 0.512 & 29826 \\
 & Ln paga & 0.238*** & 0.120 & 29778 \\
  & Ln kapital & 0.627*** & 0.373 & 29826 \\
  & Ln aktive & 0.842*** & 0.457 & 29818 \\
 \addlinespace
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{2012}}
 & Ln shitje & 0.923*** & 0.492 & 27050 \\
 & Ln paga & 0.245*** & 0.135 & 26995 \\
 & Ln kapital & 0.593*** & 0.327 & 27050 \\
 & Ln aktive & 0.957*** & 0.425 & 27042 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{}\label{fig:}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

i would use the packages `booktabs`, `threepartable` and `siunitx` and reorganised table similarly as suggest [leandriis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134144/leandriis) in his(her) answer:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{threeparttable}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{S[table-format=1.3,
                        table-space-text-post=\tnote{***}]}
                }
    \toprule
            &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{2003}  \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
$X_{it}$    & {Ln shitje}       & {Ln paga}         & {Ln kapital}      & {Ln aktive}       \\
    \midrule
export      & 0.699\tnote{***}  & 0.192\tnote{***}  & 0.646\tnote{***}  & 0.779\tnote{***}  \\
R-squared   & 0.463             & 0.047             & 0.390             & 0.429             \\
N           & {24909}           & {24881}           & {24909}           & {24903}           \\
    \midrule
            &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{2008} \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
export      & 0.837\tnote{***}  & 0.238\tnote{***}  & 0.627***          & 0.842***          \\
R-squared   & 0.512             & 0.120             & 0.373             & 0.4               \\
N           & {29826}           & {29778}           & {29826}           & {29818}           \\
  \midrule
            &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{2012} \\
  \cmidrule{2-5}
export      & 0.923\tnote{***}  & 0.245\tnote{***}  & 0.593\tnote{***}  & 0.957\tnote{***}  \\
R-squared   & 0.492             & 0.135             & 0.327             & 0.425             \\
N           & {27050}           & {26995}           & {27050}           & {27042}           \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
    \begin{tablenotes}[para]
    \item[***] ???
    \end{tablenotes}
    \caption{some caption}
\label{fig:}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

Note:

- `threeparttable` enable to write table notes below table
- captions at table are usual on the top of table