# Rescaling a table not from within the table environment

Tags: tables, floats, environments, scaling

Is there a way to rescale a table, not from within the `table` environment?

I know that scaling can be changed from within the `table` environment, as in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10863/is-there-a-way-to-slightly-shrink-a-table-including-font-size-to-fit-within-th) example. But I would like it to be from outside. That is, I am looking for a command to come before `\begin{table}`. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not recommended to rescale a table, as it often makes it unreadable. It's better to play with the font size or  the value of `\tabcolsep`.

Comment: I am aware of that, however, I must do it this way as I am inputting the table as an auxillary file which cannot be changed.

Comment: since the `table` environment is a float, it is not possible to wrap it in another environment for the purposes of scaling.  that would have to be done *inside* the table environment.  the only possible approach i can think of would be to redefine the table environment (to be used only temporarily) to create a wrapper that calls the "oldtable" with the scaling code inside of it.  (i'm not competent enough to try to code that.)

Answer (score 3):

As barbara beeton already said, you can't wrap a float like `table` in a box and then scale it, your need to use its content only. However, you can redefine `table` to apply the scaling code automatically to its content as shown below.
Note that this non-optimal as you should scale text to much in LaTeX and the alignment of caption and actual table (the `tabular`) can be disturbed.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{lipsum}% for example text only
\usepackage{adjustbox}% for the scaling

\let\oldtable\table
\let\endoldtable\endtable

\renewenvironment{table}[1][]%
{\oldtable[#1]\adjustbox{varwidth=\linewidth,scale=3,center}\bgroup}
{\egroup\endoldtable}

\begin{document}

\lipsum% insert example text

    \begin{table}[hp]
        \centering
        \caption{My table}\label{fig:figure1}
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
          a & b & c \\
          a & b & c \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\lipsum% insert example text


\end{document}
```