# Fit tabular* enviroment

Tags: tables, size, fit

I managed to construct a readable table.

However, I do not manage to adjust the width of the headers (photo attached). Ideally, the text that does not fit will go to the next line. Would you have any suggestion on that?

[image]

Here the code:

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\begin{table}
    \caption{tabular*}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{6}{c} }
    \toprule
        Reference         & Laminate      & Veil      & $\bar{c}$  & $G$\textsubscript{IC} vs. baseline     & $G$\textsubscript{IIC} vs. baseline \\
        \midrule
        \mr{Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a}} & Carbon/epoxy & \mr{CoPA} & \mr{21} & \mr{59} & \mr{1.14} \\
        &   Carbon/vynil ester     &        &        &        &   \\
        Barjasteh \cite{Barjasteh2017} & Carbon/benzoxazine & PA12 & 12 & 17 & 1.25   \\ 
        Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015}    & Glass/vynil ester  & PA66 & 17 & 25 & 1.14 \\ 
        O'Donovan \cite{ODonovan2014}   & Glass/polyester & PA66 & 9 & 11.5 & 1.32 \\ 
        Ram\'irez \cite{Ramirez2015}    & Carbon/epoxy & PEEK & 9 & 11.5 & 1.32 \\ 
        Ni \cite{Ni2015}    & Carbon/epoxy & Aramid & 16 & 15 & 1.44 \\ 
        \mr{Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a}} & Carbon/epoxy & \mr{CoPE} & \mr{23} & \mr{12} & \mr{1.38} \\
        &   Carbon/vynil ester     &        &        &        &   \\
        Wong \cite{Wong2017}    & Carbon/epoxy & Kevlar & 26 & 12 & 1.44 \\ 
        Fitzmaurize \cite{Fitzmaurice2016}  & Glass/polyester & PET & 45 & 20 & 1.41 \\ 
        Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015}    & Glass/vynil ester & PET & 45 & 20 & 1.41  \\ 
        \mr{Beylergil \cite{Beylergil2018}} & \mr{Carbon/epoxy} & \mr{PA66} & 17 & \mr{19.90} & \mr{1.14} \\
        &       &        &   50     &        &   \\
        \mr{Ram\'irez \cite{Ramirez2015}} & \mr{Carbon/epoxy} & \mr{PPS} & 7 to 35 & 10 & \mr{1.30} \\
        &       &        &   8 to 22     &   14     &   \\  
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tabular*` is very uncommon. Also setting `\tabcolsep` to 0pt is really not recommended. I recommend to break the long table headers into two lines and use a reasonable value of `\tabcolsep` with the normal `tabular` environment.

The following should do it. As you didn't provided a full code example with the used class and packages your results may vary a little.

If it still does not fit you might want to decrease the font size a little (`\small`) or just [let the table go into the margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39436/2975). Finally you could [shrink the table to `\textwidth`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10864/2975) which is not recommended because scaling text doesn't look good as it gives non-standard font sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for example text only

\newcommand\mr{}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\setlength\tabcolsep{4.4pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\begin{table}
   \setlength\belowcaptionskip{\abovecaptionskip}
   \setlength\abovecaptionskip{0pt}
\centering
    \caption{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c} }
    \toprule
        Reference         & Laminate      & Veil      & $\bar{c}$  & $G$\textsubscript{IC}  vs.{}    & $G$\textsubscript{IIC} vs.{}  \\
                  &        &        &    & baseline     &  baseline \\
        \midrule
        \mr{Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a}} & Carbon/epoxy & \mr{CoPA} & \mr{21} & \mr{59} & \mr{1.14} \\
        &   Carbon/vynil ester     &        &        &        &   \\
        Barjasteh \cite{Barjasteh2017} & Carbon/benzoxazine & PA12 & 12 & 17 & 1.25   \\ 
        Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015}    & Glass/vynil ester  & PA66 & 17 & 25 & 1.14 \\ 
        O'Donovan \cite{ODonovan2014}   & Glass/polyester & PA66 & 9 & 11.5 & 1.32 \\ 
        Ram\'irez \cite{Ramirez2015}    & Carbon/epoxy & PEEK & 9 & 11.5 & 1.32 \\ 
        Ni \cite{Ni2015}    & Carbon/epoxy & Aramid & 16 & 15 & 1.44 \\ 
        \mr{Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a}} & Carbon/epoxy & \mr{CoPE} & \mr{23} & \mr{12} & \mr{1.38} \\
        &   Carbon/vynil ester     &        &        &        &   \\
        Wong \cite{Wong2017}    & Carbon/epoxy & Kevlar & 26 & 12 & 1.44 \\ 
        Fitzmaurize \cite{Fitzmaurice2016}  & Glass/polyester & PET & 45 & 20 & 1.41 \\ 
        Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015}    & Glass/vynil ester & PET & 45 & 20 & 1.41  \\ 
        \mr{Beylergil \cite{Beylergil2018}} & \mr{Carbon/epoxy} & \mr{PA66} & 17 & \mr{19.90} & \mr{1.14} \\
        &       &        &   50     &        &   \\
        \mr{Ram\'irez \cite{Ramirez2015}} & \mr{Carbon/epoxy} & \mr{PPS} & 7 to 35 & 10 & \mr{1.30} \\
        &       &        &   8 to 22     &   14     &   \\  
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's too much space between the first and the second row of the header, in my opinion, I would use `\makecell`.

Comment: Dear Martin. Thanks for your answer. What if I want to keep writing text in the same cell (your solution is very useful for the short example that I posted, but for longer sentenes the words keep moving away from the cell).

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use `multirow`, I find it simpler to declare what cells have to be split.

Using `\addlinespace` instead of `\extrarowheight` ensures uniform spacing.

I set the first column flush left and no centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
% local settings
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\caption{tabular*}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{5}{c} @{}}
\toprule
Reference & Laminate & Veil & $\bar{c}$ &
  \splitcell{$G_{\mathrm{IC}}$ vs. \\ baseline} &
  \splitcell{$G_{\mathrm{IIC}}$ vs. \\ baseline} \\
\midrule
Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a} &
  \splitcell{Carbon/epoxy \\ Carbon/vynil ester} &
  CoPA & 21 & 59 & 1.14 \\
\addlinespace
Barjasteh \cite{Barjasteh2017} &
  Carbon/benzoxazine &
  PA12 & 12 & 17 & 1.25   \\ 
\addlinespace
Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015} &
  Glass/vynil ester &
  PA66 & 17 & 25 & 1.14 \\ 
\addlinespace
O'Donovan \cite{ODonovan2014} &
  Glass/polyester &
  PA66 & 9 & 11.5 & 1.32 \\ 
\addlinespace
Ram\'irez \cite{Ramirez2015} &
  Carbon/epoxy &
  PEEK & 9 & 11.5 & 1.32 \\ 
\addlinespace
Ni \cite{Ni2015} &
  Carbon/epoxy &
  Aramid & 16 & 15 & 1.44 \\ 
\addlinespace
Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a} &
  \splitcell{Carbon/epoxy \\ Carbon/vynil ester} &
  CoPE & 23 & 12 & 1.38 \\
\addlinespace
Wong \cite{Wong2017} &
  Carbon/epoxy &
  Kevlar & 26 & 12 & 1.44 \\ 
\addlinespace
Fitzmaurize \cite{Fitzmaurice2016} &
  Glass/polyester &
  PET & 45 & 20 & 1.41 \\ 
\addlinespace
Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015} &
  Glass/vynil ester &
  PET & 45 & 20 & 1.41  \\ 
\addlinespace
Beylergil \cite{Beylergil2018} &
  Carbon/epoxy &
  PA66 & \splitcell{17 \\ 50} & 19.90 & 1.14 \\
\addlinespace
Ram\'irez \cite{Ramirez2015} &
  Carbon/epoxy &
  PPS & \splitcell{7 to 35 \\ 8 to 22} & 10 & 1.30 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also consider `siunitx`. In the case of `S` columns, special cell contents has to be braced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
% local settings
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\caption{tabular*}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  c
  c
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Reference & Laminate & Veil & $\bar{c}$ &
  {\splitcell{$G_{\mathrm{IC}}$ vs. \\ baseline}} &
  {\splitcell{$G_{\mathrm{IIC}}$ vs. \\ baseline}} \\
\midrule
Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a} &
  \splitcell{Carbon/epoxy \\ Carbon/vynil ester} &
  CoPA & 21 & 59 & 1.14 \\
\addlinespace
Barjasteh \cite{Barjasteh2017} &
  Carbon/benzoxazine &
  PA12 & 12 & 17 & 1.25   \\ 
\addlinespace
Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015} &
  Glass/vynil ester &
  PA66 & 17 & 25 & 1.14 \\ 
\addlinespace
O'Donovan \cite{ODonovan2014} &
  Glass/polyester &
  PA66 & 9 & 11.5 & 1.32 \\ 
\addlinespace
Ram\'irez \cite{Ramirez2015} &
  Carbon/epoxy &
  PEEK & 9 & 11.5 & 1.32 \\ 
\addlinespace
Ni \cite{Ni2015} &
  Carbon/epoxy &
  Aramid & 16 & 15 & 1.44 \\ 
\addlinespace
Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a} &
  \splitcell{Carbon/epoxy \\ Carbon/vynil ester} &
  CoPE & 23 & 12 & 1.38 \\
\addlinespace
Wong \cite{Wong2017} &
  Carbon/epoxy &
  Kevlar & 26 & 12 & 1.44 \\ 
\addlinespace
Fitzmaurize \cite{Fitzmaurice2016} &
  Glass/polyester &
  PET & 45 & 20 & 1.41 \\ 
\addlinespace
Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015} &
  Glass/vynil ester &
  PET & 45 & 20 & 1.41  \\ 
\addlinespace
Beylergil \cite{Beylergil2018} &
  Carbon/epoxy &
  PA66 & {\splitcell[r]{17 \\ 50}} & 19.90 & 1.14 \\
\addlinespace
Ram\'irez \cite{Ramirez2015} &
  Carbon/epoxy &
  PPS & {\splitcell{\numrange{7}{35} \\ \numrange{8}{22}}} & 10 & 1.30 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A variant, based on `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}%{table-sep}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness} {0.3pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, caption}

\newcommand{\mr}{\relax}

\begin{document}
%
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \caption{tabular + makecell}
\begin{tabular}{ *{6}{c} }
    \toprule
        Reference & Laminate & Veil & $\bar{c}$ & \makecell{$G_\text{IC}$ vs. \\ baseline} & \makecell{$G_\text{IIC}$ vs. \\ baseline} \\
        \midrule
        \mr{Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a}} & Carbon/epoxy & \mr{CoPA} & \mr{21} & \mr{59} & \mr{1.14} \\
        & Carbon/vynil ester & & & & \\
        Barjasteh \cite{Barjasteh2017} & Carbon/benzoxazine & PA12 & 12 & 17 & 1.25 \\
        Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015} & Glass/vynil ester & PA66 & 17 & 25 & 1.14 \\
        O'Donovan \cite{ODonovan2014} & Glass/polyester & PA66 & 9 & 11.5 & 1.32 \\
        Ramírez \cite{Ramirez2015} & Carbon/epoxy & PEEK & 9 & 11.5 & 1.32 \\
        Ni \cite{Ni2015} & Carbon/epoxy & Aramid & 16 & 15 & 1.44 \\
        \mr{Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a}} & Carbon/epoxy & \mr{CoPE} & \mr{23} & \mr{12} & \mr{1.38} \\
        & Carbon/vynil ester & & & & \\
        Wong \cite{Wong2017} & Carbon/epoxy & Kevlar & 26 & 12 & 1.44 \\
        Fitzmaurize \cite{Fitzmaurice2016} & Glass/polyester & PET & 45 & 20 & 1.41 \\
        Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015} & Glass/vynil ester & PET & 45 & 20 & 1.41 \\
        \mr{Beylergil \cite{Beylergil2018}} & \mr{Carbon/epoxy} & \mr{PA66} & 17 & \mr{19.90} & \mr{1.14} \\
        & & & 50 & & \\
        \mr{Ramírez\cite{Ramirez2015}} & \mr{Carbon/epoxy} & \mr{PPS} & 7 to 35 & 10 & \mr{1.30} \\
        & & & 8 to 22 & 14 & \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You might prefer to use a `\tabularx` environment. Here is an example: add to your preamble

```
\usepackage{ragged2e,siunitx, tabularx}
```

and use this code:

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} \setlength\extrarowheight{5pt} 
\begin{table} \centering \caption{tabular + makecell} 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c>{\Centering}X*{4}{c} } 
\toprule 
Reference & Laminate & Veil & \makecell{$\bar{\beta}$ \\(\si{g\per\square m})} & \makecell{$\omega$\\ (\si{\um})} & \makecell{$\rho$ \\(\si{g\per m\cubed })} \\ \midrule Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a} & Carbon/epoxy (non-crimp and plain-weave fabrics) & \mr{CoPA} & \mr{21} & \mr{59} & 1.14 \\ \bottomrule 
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That one is awesome! Now everything looks good inside the table. However the table itself is uncentred on the page. Would you kindly have any suggestion?

Comment: Normally, it is centred w.r.t. the margins (see the page frame in the image).vuia the directive `\centering` – unless your preamble inhibits this for some reason. Could you post a minimal example showing the problem?

Comment: \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\begin{table}
 \centering
 \caption{tabular + makecell}
 \begin{tabular}{ *{6}{c} }
 \toprule
 Reference         & Laminate      & Veil      & $\bar{\beta}$ (g/m\textsuperscript{2})     & $\omega$ ($\mu$m)      & $\rho$ (g/m\textsuperscript{3}) \\
 \midrule
 Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a} & \makecell{Carbon/epoxy (non-crimp \\ and plain-weave fabrics)} & \mr{CoPA} & \mr{21} & \mr{59} & 1.14 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Comment: @Santi: I've  posted a solution based on `tabularx` and `ragged2e`. I added `siunitx` to have more correct units (the symbol for `micro` is not an ordinary `mu`), simpler to type.