# Minimizing Extra Spaces in Exam Headers and possible improvements

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx, bounding-box

I am an educator in mathematics and prefer using LaTeX for typesetting documents. However, the dean of our faculty provided us with a Word version for creating exam headers. I tried to convert it to LaTeX as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % not needed in new latex versions
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,amsthm,mathtools,systeme}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,moreverb} % tableau de signe moreverb not needed
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%----------
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}
%----------
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} %pour inserer une page pdf
\usepackage{awesomebox} %takecare
%---- Dimensions des marges ---
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.5cm}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing
%---- pages numbers with tikz---
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\tikz{ \node [rectangle, draw = black] (rectangle) at (0,0) {\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}   }}
}
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}
%----New Structure Exercice -----
\newtheoremstyle{sboxexc}% name of the style to be used
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {0pt}%  of space to indent
  {\bfseries}% name of head font
  {}% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}}% Manually specify head
\newcounter{counter}
\setcounter{counter}{1}
\theoremstyle{sboxexc}
\newcommand{\optionaltext}{}
\newtheorem*{Exc}{\shadowbox{\ding{228} Exercice \arabic{counter}\optionaltext}}
\newcommand{\exo}[2][]{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{#2}\begin{Exc}\normalfont\mbox{}\par}
\newcommand{\finexo}{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{}\end{Exc}\addtocounter{counter}{1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\isEquivTo}[1]{\underset{#1}{\sim}}
\newcommand*{\transp}[2][-3mu]{\ensuremath{\mskip1mu\prescript{\smash{\mathrm t\mkern#1}}{}{\mathstrut#2}}}%
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rg}{rg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\vect}{Vect}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mat}{Mat}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{sfaxlogo}{RGB}{127,176,206}
\colorlet{sfaxblue}{sfaxlogo!70!black!60!blue}
%\pagestyle{empty}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%------------------------------------------------
    \usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{10.4pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{10.4pt}
%------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%begin entete%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 {\scriptsize\bfseries  \begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|c|@{}c@{}|}
      \cline{1-1}  \cline{3-3}
      \begin{tabular}{c}
 Ministère de l'Enseignement\\
 Supérieur\\
 et de la Recherche Scientifique\\
\textbf{-- -- -- $\star\star\star$ -- -- --}\\
 Université de xxxxx\\
\textbf{-- -- -- $\star\star\star$ -- -- --}\\
 Faculté des Sciences \'Economiques\\
 et de Gestion de xxxxx\\
        \vspace{-0.5cm}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} \\
      \end{tabular}
      & &
     \begin{tabular}{0l|p{8cm}}
         Matière & Mathématiques II (Analyse)\\ \hline
         Niveau et Filière & Première année (Licence en Sciences \'Economiques)\\ \hline
         Enseignant & Monsieur xxxxxxxxxxxx\\ \hline
         Session & Principale (Juin 2023) \\ \hline
         Durée & 2 heures\\ \hline
       Nombre de Pages & 2 \\
      \end{tabular}\\
      \cline{1-1}  \cline{3-3}
    \end{tabular}
%-------------- FIN DE L'ENTETE----------------------
\vspace{0.2cm}

\noindent{\underline{\bf Directives pédagogiques :}}
\begin{itemize}
  \item [\circled{R}] Aucune documentation n'est permise.
  \item [\circled{R}] La qualité de la rédaction, la clarté et la précision des interprétations entreront pour une part importante dans l'appréciation finale.
\end{itemize}}
%\vspace{-0.5cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% début exercice%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\exo{: ($4$ points)}

\finexo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fin exercice%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% début exercice%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\exo{: ($5$ points)}

\finexo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fin exercice%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%-encouragement--
\begin{flushright}
  {\large\ding{95}} {\large\ding{95}}
\emph{\textbf{\underline{Bon travail}}} {\large\ding{95}}
{\large\ding{95}}
\end{flushright}
%---
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image]

> However, the header takes up a great deal of space. I would like to minimize the extra spaces. Additionally, any suggestions for improvement are appreciated. I want the end of the second table to be at the same level as the text boundary.

Comment: If you mean an the extra space in left margin, note that a  tabular  is positioned just  like a big single character. It start  a paragraph no matter if there are really a paragraph after it, so by default is indented as set in `\parindent`. Change this length to 0pt or use `\noindent` just before the tabular.

Comment: Off topic: `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, and `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, so some streamlining is possible.

Comment: @Fran I'm sorry since I don't understand your comment

Comment: @Student  Just change the first `\begin{tabular}` by `\noindent\begin{tabular}`. This solve your problem?   (BTW,  pay attention to your own comment in the second line of code).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Fran but there is also some extra spaces in the two tables

Comment: @Student Remove the `\vspace{-0.5cm}` before the image and set both `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit`  as low as possible (,i.e., 9pt, less will have  ugly results).

Comment: @Fran I'm sorry since the file does not compiles to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two different fixes:

[image: mwe]

The first (the recommended) is a single table using  tabulary, multirow and array, and the other is your nested tabulars with the fixes of the comments, plus  tabularx to fit the text boundary as you asked in your last edit

(note: in the edits, please add what you need to clarify the question but do not remove/change the original post, since then the comments or answers could have no sense for another users).

(note: I removed parts of the preamble that are  irrelevant for the issue in order to simplify the example, but that maybe your will need in your working document.  So, to check that solutions in your working document do not change the preamble except to add mentioned packages (i.e., just add the second line of the code below.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,tabulary,multirow,array} 
\usepackage{graphicx,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement

\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\newtheoremstyle{sboxexc}% name of the style to be used
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {0pt}%  of space to indent
  {\bfseries}% name of head font
  {}% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}}% Manually specify head
\newcounter{counter}
\setcounter{counter}{1}
\theoremstyle{sboxexc}
\newcommand{\optionaltext}{}
\newtheorem*{Exc}{\shadowbox{\ding{228} Exercice \arabic{counter}\optionaltext}}
\newcommand{\exo}[2][]{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{#2}\begin{Exc}\normalfont\mbox{}\par}
\newcommand{\finexo}{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{}\end{Exc}\addtocounter{counter}{1}}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{9pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{9pt}


\begin{document}


% Method 1: A single table

\begin{table}[t]
\scriptsize\bfseries
\renewcommand\arraystretch{3.3}%
\extrarowheight-2pt
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|C|L|l|l|}
\cline{3-4}\cline{1-1}
\multirow{6}{=}{\centering
 Ministère de l'Enseignement \par Supérieur  \par et de la Recherche Scientifique\par
\textbf{-- -- -- $\star\star\star$ -- -- --}\par
 Université de xxxxx\par
\textbf{-- -- -- $\star\star\star$ -- -- --}\par
 Faculté des Sciences \'Economiques \par et de Gestion de xxxxx\par
\medskip\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 
}
& & Matière & Mathématiques II (Analyse)\\\cline{3-4}
& & Niveau et Filière & Première année (Licence en Sciences \'Economiques)\\\cline{3-4}
& & Enseignant & Monsieur xxxxxxxxxxxx\\\cline{3-4}
& & Session & Principale (Juin 2023) \\\cline{3-4}
& & Durée & 2 heures\\\cline{3-4}
& & Nombre de Pages & 2 \\\cline{1-1}\cline{3-4}
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

% Method 2: Fix your table with tabularx 


 {\scriptsize\bfseries  \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|@{}c@{}|X|@{}c@{}|}
      \cline{1-1}  \cline{3-3}
      \begin{tabular}{c}
 Ministère de l'Enseignement\\
 Supérieur\\
 et de la Recherche Scientifique\\
\textbf{-- -- -- $\star\star\star$ -- -- --}\\
 Université de xxxxx\\
\textbf{-- -- -- $\star\star\star$ -- -- --}\\
 Faculté des Sciences \'Economiques\\
 et de Gestion de xxxxx\\
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} \\
      \end{tabular}
      & &
     \begin{tabular}{0l|p{8.3cm}}
         Matière & Mathématiques II (Analyse)\\ \hline
         Niveau et Filière & Première année (Licence en Sciences \'Economiques)\\ \hline
         Enseignant & Monsieur xxxxxxxxxxxx\\ \hline
         Session & Principale (Juin 2023) \\ \hline
         Durée & 2 heures\\ \hline
       Nombre de Pages & 2 \\
      \end{tabular}\\
      \cline{1-1}  \cline{3-3}
    \end{tabularx}

\vspace{0.2cm}

\noindent{\underline{\bf Directives pédagogiques :}}
\begin{itemize}
  \item [\circled{R}] Aucune documentation n'est permise.
  \item [\circled{R}] La qualité de la rédaction, la clarté et la précision des interprétations entreront pour une part importante dans l'appréciation finale.
\end{itemize}}
\exo{: ($4$ points)}
\finexo
\exo{: ($5$ points)}
\finexo
\begin{flushright}
  {\large\ding{95}} {\large\ding{95}}
\emph{\textbf{\underline{Bon travail}}} {\large\ding{95}}
{\large\ding{95}}
\end{flushright}
%---
\end{document}
```

> Additionally, any suggestions for improvement are appreciated.

OK:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,tabulary,multirow,array,booktabs,xcolor} 
\usepackage{pgfornament} 
\usepackage{graphicx,amsthm,mathtools}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement

\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\newtheoremstyle{sboxexc}% name of the style to be used
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {0pt}%  of space to indent
  {\bfseries}% name of head font
  {}% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}}% Manually specify head
\newcounter{counter}
\setcounter{counter}{1}
\theoremstyle{sboxexc}
\newcommand{\optionaltext}{}
\newtheorem*{Exc}{\shadowbox{\ding{228} Exercice \arabic{counter}\optionaltext}}
\newcommand{\exo}[2][]{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{#2}\begin{Exc}\normalfont\mbox{}\par}
\newcommand{\finexo}{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{}\end{Exc}\addtocounter{counter}{1}}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[t]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.3}%\extrarowheight-2pt
\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{5.2cm}X>{\color{green!40!black}\sffamily}l>{\color{blue!40!black}\sffamily}l}
\toprule
\multirow{6}{=}{\centering%\bfseries
 Ministère de l'Enseignement Supérieur et de la Recherche Scientifique


\pgfornament[width=2cm]{83}

 Université de xxxxx\par

\pgfornament[width=2cm]{83}

Faculté des Sciences Économiques et de Gestion de xxxxx

\medskip\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 

}
& &  Matière:  & Mathématiques II (Analyse)\\
& & Niveau et Filière:  & Première année (Licence en Sciences \'Economiques)\\
& & Enseignant: & Monsieur Dr. Moreau \\
& & Session: & Principale (\today) \\
& & Durée: & 2 heures\\
& & Nombre de Pages: & 2 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\subsubsection*{Directives pédagogiques:}

\begin{itemize}\itemsep1ex
  \item [\textregistered] Aucune documentation n'est permise.
  \item [\textregistered] La qualité de la rédaction, la clarté et la précision des interprétations entreront pour une part importante dans l'appréciation finale.
\end{itemize}

\exo{: ($4$ points)}
\finexo
\exo{: ($5$ points)}
\finexo
\begin{flushright}
  {\large\ding{95}} {\large\ding{95}}
\emph{\textbf{\underline{Bon travail}}} {\large\ding{95}}
{\large\ding{95}}
\end{flushright}
%---
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. please just add a space betwen the end of the table and Directives pédagogiques. I replaced ```\vspace{0.2cm}

\noindent{\underline{\bf Directives pédagogiques :}}``` by ```\vspace{0.7cm}

\noindent{\underline{\bf Directives pédagogiques :}}``` but the space does not change

Comment: @Student `\vspace` ignored in places as the top of the page or after a top float where usually it have no sense. You can force the spacing with \vspace*, but in general, when you insert manually spaces, your are going in the wrong direction, for instance, formating manually headers (bold and underlined text)   instead of use some like  `\subsubsection*` that will take care of the spacing automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I used ```{\scriptsize\bfseries \subsubsection*{\underline{Directives pédagogiques:}}
    \begin{itemize}\itemsep1ex
      \item [\textregistered] Aucune documentation n'est permise.
      \item [\textregistered] La qualité de la rédaction, la clarté et la précision des interprétations entreront pour une part importante dans l'appréciation finale.
    \end{itemize}}``` the title of subsection is always in the same size. I like the size will be less

Comment: @Student (1) If you do not want the default style of commands as `\section{foo}` (font type, size, color, spacing above and below, whatever ...)  change that style in the preamble, do not try to re-format  the argument "foo" manually in the text. (2) The style it is a matter of taste,  but underlines always make the text less legible,  heavy and cluttered.

Answer (score 1):

Well, because you have already made some advanced formatting, I am wondering why can't we just use `\resizebox{<*width-value*>}{<*height-value*>}{<*content*>}` to embrace the two tabular forms and if row height seems problematic [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159260/297046) answer makes it clear. I can understand this should be in comment section of your question but I have not enough reputation to do so.

Comment: please provide me the code in order to compile it. Thanks

Comment: Resize a table to fit the margins is always a bad idea in table design because you will not have any control of the final font size and thickness of the rules, so inconsistent with the rest of the document, beside that even if you can shrink or stretch a normal font to be exactly as big as `\huge`, or as little as `\tiny`, the result is not the same: the font will be not  the same (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/641783/11604)).

Comment: @Student as @Fran has already referred to some discrepancies to this method, I am not editing my answer. But to see the outcome you can add `\resizebox{0.62\textwidth}{!}{` at the beginning of `line 86` and a closing `}` to at the end of `line 93`.