Reduce the Height of This Latex Table
Given the following two latex tables, I want each height to be reduced such that the two tables will fit on a single page. I do not want the table format deformed.
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = de_GB
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[hmargin={2cm,15mm},vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{Times, bm}% for font that is close to times new roman
\usepackage[font=large,
labelfont=bf,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small]{subcaption}

\usepackage{inputenc,float,caption,subcaption,enumitem}
\usepackage[font=large,labelfont=bf,font=normalfont,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,font=bf,labelsep=colon]{subcaption}
\usepackage{csquotes} %for single quoatation mark

\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,graphicx,mathtools,amsthm,tikz,inputenc,float,caption,subcaption,enumitem,subcaption,tocbibind}
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
%\usepackage{cite,citeall,citehack,citesort,citeref,}
\captionsetup{font={small}}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

% Adjust vertical row height and column spacing
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.2} % Reduce row spacing
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}       % Reduce column padding

\begin{document}%\layout
 
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \small
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{$ss1d=10$}
    \caption{MAE Values of Evaluation for MA(2) Models When $n = 25$ \label{tabb32}}
    \begin{tblr}
        {
            hline{1} = {2-Y}{4pt}, hline{2} = {2-Y}{2pt},   hline{3} = {1-Z}{3pt}, hline{4-7} = {1-Y}{solid},   hline{8} = {1-Z}{2pt}, hline{9-12} = {1-Y}{solid},  hline{13} = {1-Z}{2pt}, hline{14-17} = {1-Z}{solid},    hline{18} = {1-Z}{2pt}, hline{19-22} = {1-Z}{solid},    hline{23} = {1-Z}{4pt}, %   hline{even [3-Z]} = {solid, gray!30}, hline{2-Z} = {2pt},
            vline{1} = {3-Z}{4pt}, vline{2} = {1-Z}{3pt}, vline{3-4} = {2-Z}{solid}, vline{5} = {1-Z}{2pt}, vline{6-7} = {2-Z}{solid}, vline{8} = {1-Z}{2pt}, vline{9-10} = {2-Z}{solid}, vline{11} = {1-Z}{3pt}, vline{12} = {3-Z}{4pt},% vline{23} = {3-Z}{2pt},% vline{Z} = {3-Z}{2pt}, vline{2-Y}={2pt},
            colsep=4pt, colspec={r X[c, font=\normalsize] *{11}{X[c]} c}, cell{1}{2-Y}={bg=gray!80}, cell{3-Z}{Z}={bg=lightgray, cmd=\rotcell[cc]},  cell{2}{2-Y}={bg=gray!30,font=\bfseries}, vspan=even
        }
        &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    SSS &&&    \SetCell[c=3]{c}    RRR &&&    \SetCell[c=3]{c}    TTT Length &&& \\
        \SetCell[r=1]{c,$} & \bm{\vartheta = 0.8}    & \bm{\vartheta = 0.9}    & \bm{\vartheta = .95}    &   \bm{\vartheta = 0.8}   & \bm{\vartheta = 0.9}    & \bm{\vartheta = .95}    & \bm{\vartheta = 0.8}    &   \bm{\vartheta = 0.9}  & \bm{\vartheta = .95}    &  \\%or
        %\SetCell[r=1]{c,$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$}& {\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} \\
        \textbf{MMM}  & 1.14          & 1.17          & 1.13          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0           & 0           & 6       & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\bm{ss1d=177}$\\
        \textbf{NNN}  & 0.09          & 0.11          & 0.12          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18          & 18          & 14          &\\
        \textbf{OOO}  & 0.11          & 0.13          & 0.15          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18          & 18          & 0           &\\
        \textbf{PPP} & 0.09          & 19.12          & 17.15          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10          & 10          & 9           &\\
        \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{50.83} & \textbf{40.84} & \textbf{20.65} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{20} & \textbf{23} & \textbf{19} &\\  
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \textbf{MMM}  & 13.41          & 63.51       & 93.38          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0           & 0           & 6           & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\bm{ss1d=31}$\\
        \textbf{NNN}  & 33.27          & 93.34       & 30.36          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18          & 18          & 14          &\\
        \textbf{OOO}  & 31.32          & 35.4        & 37.44          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18          & 18          & 0           &\\
        \textbf{PPP} & 30.28          & 38.36       & 38.44          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10          & 10          & 9           &\\
        \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{19.94} & \textbf{27} & \textbf{16.55} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{21} & \textbf{22} & \textbf{17} &\\ 
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
        \textbf{MMM} & 55.69          & 56.84       & 55.63          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0          & 0          & 6           & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\bm{ss1d=51}$\\
        \textbf{NNN}  & 56.46          & 54.56       & 59.6           & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18         & 18         & 14          &\\
        \textbf{OOO}  & 55.54          & 57.66       & 35.73          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18         & 18         & 0           &\\
        \textbf{PPP} & 75.47          & 85.6        & 85.73          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10         & 10         & 9           &\\
        \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{26.97} & \textbf{38} & \textbf{26.52} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{5} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{20} &\\    
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \textbf{MMM}  & 116.37         & 116.68         & 171.26         & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0           & 0           & 6      & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\bm{ss1d=110}$\\
        \textbf{NNN}  & 140.91         & 116.12         & 117.19         & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18          & 18          & 14          &\\
        \textbf{OOO}  & 121.08         & 119.32         & 181.45         & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18          & 18          & 0           &\\
        \textbf{PPP} & 150.94         & 191.2          & 191.47         & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10          & 10          & 9           &\\
        \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{25.18} & \textbf{53.18} & \textbf{45.93} & 16 & 18 & 0 & \textbf{17} & \textbf{17} & \textbf{17} &\\ 
        
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \small
        \settowidth\rotheadsize{$ss1d=10$}
        \caption{MAE Values of Evaluation for MA(2) Models When $n = 25$ \label{tabb32}}
        \begin{tblr}
            {
                hline{1} = {2-Y}{4pt}, hline{2} = {2-Y}{2pt},   hline{3} = {1-Z}{3pt}, hline{4-7} = {1-Y}{solid},   hline{8} = {1-Z}{2pt}, hline{9-12} = {1-Y}{solid},  hline{13} = {1-Z}{2pt}, hline{14-17} = {1-Z}{solid},    hline{18} = {1-Z}{2pt}, hline{19-22} = {1-Z}{solid},    hline{23} = {1-Z}{4pt}, %   hline{even [3-Z]} = {solid, gray!30}, hline{2-Z} = {2pt},
                vline{1} = {3-Z}{4pt}, vline{2} = {1-Z}{3pt}, vline{3-4} = {2-Z}{solid}, vline{5} = {1-Z}{2pt}, vline{6-7} = {2-Z}{solid}, vline{8} = {1-Z}{2pt}, vline{9-10} = {2-Z}{solid}, vline{11} = {1-Z}{3pt}, vline{12} = {3-Z}{4pt},% vline{23} = {3-Z}{2pt},% vline{Z} = {3-Z}{2pt}, vline{2-Y}={2pt},
                colsep=4pt, colspec={r X[c, font=\normalsize] *{11}{X[c]} c}, cell{1}{2-Y}={bg=gray!80}, cell{3-Z}{Z}={bg=lightgray, cmd=\rotcell[cc]},  cell{2}{2-Y}={bg=gray!30,font=\bfseries}, vspan=even
            }
            &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    SSS &&&    \SetCell[c=3]{c}    RRR &&&    \SetCell[c=3]{c}    TTT Length &&& \\
            \SetCell[r=1]{c,$} & \bm{\vartheta = 0.8}    & \bm{\vartheta = 0.9}    & \bm{\vartheta = .95}    &   \bm{\vartheta = 0.8}   & \bm{\vartheta = 0.9}    & \bm{\vartheta = .95}    & \bm{\vartheta = 0.8}    &   \bm{\vartheta = 0.9}  & \bm{\vartheta = .95}    &  \\%or
            %\SetCell[r=1]{c,$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} & {\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$}& {\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} \\
            \textbf{MMM}  & 1.14          & 1.17          & 1.13          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0           & 0           & 6       & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\bm{ss1d=177}$\\
            \textbf{NNN}  & 0.09          & 0.11          & 0.12          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18          & 18          & 14          &\\
            \textbf{OOO}  & 0.11          & 0.13          & 0.15          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18          & 18          & 0           &\\
            \textbf{PPP} & 0.09          & 19.12          & 17.15          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10          & 10          & 9           &\\
            \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{50.83} & \textbf{40.84} & \textbf{20.65} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{20} & \textbf{23} & \textbf{19} &\\  
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \textbf{MMM}  & 13.41          & 63.51       & 93.38          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0           & 0           & 6           & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\bm{ss1d=31}$\\
            \textbf{NNN}  & 33.27          & 93.34       & 30.36          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18          & 18          & 14          &\\
            \textbf{OOO}  & 31.32          & 35.4        & 37.44          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18          & 18          & 0           &\\
            \textbf{PPP} & 30.28          & 38.36       & 38.44          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10          & 10          & 9           &\\
            \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{19.94} & \textbf{27} & \textbf{16.55} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{21} & \textbf{22} & \textbf{17} &\\ 
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
            \textbf{MMM} & 55.69          & 56.84       & 55.63          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0          & 0          & 6           & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\bm{ss1d=51}$\\
            \textbf{NNN}  & 56.46          & 54.56       & 59.6           & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18         & 18         & 14          &\\
            \textbf{OOO}  & 55.54          & 57.66       & 35.73          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18         & 18         & 0           &\\
            \textbf{PPP} & 75.47          & 85.6        & 85.73          & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10         & 10         & 9           &\\
            \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{26.97} & \textbf{38} & \textbf{26.52} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{5} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{20} &\\    
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \textbf{MMM}  & 116.37         & 116.68         & 171.26         & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0           & 0           & 6      & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\bm{ss1d=110}$\\
            \textbf{NNN}  & 140.91         & 116.12         & 117.19         & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18          & 18          & 14          &\\
            \textbf{OOO}  & 121.08         & 119.32         & 181.45         & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18          & 18          & 0           &\\
            \textbf{PPP} & 150.94         & 191.2          & 191.47         & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10          & 10          & 9           &\\
            \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{25.18} & \textbf{53.18} & \textbf{45.93} & 16 & 18 & 0 & \textbf{17} & \textbf{17} & \textbf{17} &\\ 
            
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}

\end{document}

output is displaced 
Trial
I have tried to add the following chunk to my preamble but no significant change:
% Adjust spacing for table
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.85} % Reduce row height
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}        % Reduce column spacing


please confirm scale is allowed?

Please read https://betterposters.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-data-prison.html

@MadyYuvi yes, scale is allowed

Where do you have package Times from? I know only times (lowercase), which does not make sense, when using LuaLaTeX.

Have you tried replacing \small by, e.g., \footnotesize or \tiny?

Would using \enlargethispage be allowed?

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables

@cabohah Your suggestion will only reduce the font size and not the cell height.

smaller font → smaller baselineskip → smaller cell height

Your example does not work: Missing $ inserted. Please make it compile without error.

If I run your MWE, then I got the error as Missing $ inserted. <inserted text>

@cabohah I tried it; it did not work.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10863/is-there-a-way-to-slightly-shrink-a-table-including-font-size-to-fit-within-th (it's about column width instead of text height, but several answers nevertheless are suitable for your case too, at least with some minor modification).

Have you also removed the \normalsize? As long as there are larger fonts used in the table, they are relevant for the height of the cells.

My main suggestion is to switch to \footnotesize, for a 20% linear reduction in font size; \small just isn't enough. I would further place both tblr environments and their associated \caption directives in a single table environment. In addition, I would load the setspace package and issue the instruction \setstretch{0.95} immediately after \begin{table}.
Some other suggestions: (a) Don't load packages more than once; absolutely nothing good can come from this. (b) Since you're using LuaLaTeX, definitely don't load the inputenc package, and don't use the obsolete times package. Instead, load the unicode-math package and issue suitable \setmainfont and \setmathfont directives. See the code below for specific font suggestions. (c) I would also try very hard to avoid creating turgid-looking vertical and horizontal rules. Lines that are 3pt or even 4pt thick -- really?! How about rules that are half as wide -- 1pt, 1.5pt, and 2pt, respectively? (d) What's with the \large and \normalsize directives? Unless you want to make your table look like an extended ransom note, please don't change fontsizes capriciously.

% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = de_GB
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[hmargin={2cm,15mm},vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,skip=0.25\baselineskip]{caption}
%\usepackage[labelfont=bf,textfont=bf,labelsep=colon]{subcaption} % not needed
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,tikz,tocbibind,enumitem}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS} % Times Roman clone
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\usepackage{csquotes,microtype,nicematrix,rotating,makecell,xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}%\layout
 
\begin{table}[p!]
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt} % Reduce column padding
    \footnotesize % <-- new
    \setstretch{0.95} % less space between rows
    \captionsetup{font=footnotesize} % <-- new
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{$ss1d=10$}
    
    %% first table
    \caption{MAE Values of Evaluation for MA(2) Models if $n = 25$} 
    \label{tabb32}
    \begin{tblr}{%
    hline{1} = {2-Y}{2.5pt}, hline{2} = {2-Y}{1.5pt},   hline{3} = {1-Z}{2pt}, hline{4-7} = {1-Y}{solid},   hline{8} = {1-Z}{1.5pt}, hline{9-12} = {1-Y}{solid},  hline{13} = {1-Z}{1.5pt}, hline{14-17} = {1-Z}{solid},    hline{18} = {1-Z}{1.5pt}, hline{19-22} = {1-Z}{solid},    hline{23} = {1-Z}{2.5pt}, %   hline{even [3-Z]} = {solid, gray!30}, hline{2-Z} = {1.5pt},
    vline{1} = {3-Z}{2.5pt}, vline{2} = {1-Z}{2pt}, vline{3-4} = {2-Z}{solid}, vline{5} = {1-Z}{1.5pt}, vline{6-7} = {2-Z}{solid}, vline{8} = {1-Z}{1.5pt}, vline{9-10} = {2-Z}{solid}, vline{11} = {1-Z}{2pt}, vline{12} = {3-Z}{2.5pt},% vline{23} = {3-Z}{1.5pt},% vline{Z} = {3-Z}{1.5pt}, vline{2-Y}={1.5pt},
    colsep=2.5pt, colspec={l *{12}{X[c]} c}, cell{1}{2-Y}={bg=gray!80}, cell{3-Z}{Z}={bg=lightgray, cmd=\rotcell[cc]},  cell{2}{2-Y}={bg=gray!30,font=\bfseries}, vspan=even
    }
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c} SSS &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} RRR &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c}    TTT Length &&& \\
    \SetCell[r=1]{c,$} & 
    $\symbf{\vartheta = 0.8}$ & $\symbf{\vartheta = 0.9}$ & $\symbf{\vartheta = .95}$ & 
    $\symbf{\vartheta = 0.8}$ & $\symbf{\vartheta = 0.9}$ & $\symbf{\vartheta = .95}$ & 
    $\symbf{\vartheta = 0.8}$ & $\symbf{\vartheta = 0.9}$ & $\symbf{\vartheta = .95}$ & \\
    \textbf{MMM} & 1.14 &  1.17 &  1.13 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 & 6 & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\symbf{ss1d=177}$\\
    \textbf{NNN} & 0.09 &  0.11 &  0.12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    \textbf{OOO} & 0.11 &  0.13 &  0.15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 0 & \\
    \textbf{PPP} & 0.09 & 19.12 & 17.15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 & 9 & \\
    \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{50.83} & \textbf{40.84} & \textbf{20.65} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{20} & \textbf{23} & \textbf{19} & \\  
    %%%%%
    \textbf{MMM} & 13.41 & 63.51 & 93.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 & 6 & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\symbf{ss1d=31}$\\
    \textbf{NNN} & 33.27 & 93.34 & 30.36 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    \textbf{OOO} & 31.32 & 35.4  & 37.44 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 0 & \\
    \textbf{PPP} & 30.28 & 38.36 & 38.44 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 & 9 & \\
    \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{19.94} & \textbf{27} & \textbf{16.55} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{21} & \textbf{22} & \textbf{17} & \\ 
    %%%%%  
    \textbf{MMM} & 55.69 & 56.84 & 55.63 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 & 6 & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\symbf{ss1d=51}$\\
    \textbf{NNN} & 56.46 & 54.56 & 59.6  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    \textbf{OOO} & 55.54 & 57.66 & 35.73 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 0 & \\
    \textbf{PPP} & 75.47 & 85.6  & 85.73 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 & 9 & \\
    \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{26.97} & \textbf{38} & \textbf{26.52} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{5} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{20} & \\    
    %%%%%
    \textbf{MMM} & 116.37 & 116.68 & 171.26 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 & 6 & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\symbf{ss1d=110}$\\
    \textbf{NNN} & 140.91 & 116.12 & 117.19 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    \textbf{OOO} & 121.08 & 119.32 & 181.45 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 0 & \\
    \textbf{PPP} & 150.94 & 191.2  & 191.47 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 & 9 & \\
    \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{25.18} & \textbf{53.18} & \textbf{45.93} & 16 & 18 & 0 & \textbf{17} & \textbf{17} & \textbf{17} & \\ 
 
    \end{tblr}

    \bigskip

    %% second table
    \caption{MAE Values of Evaluation for MA(2) Models if $n = 25$} 
    \label{tabb32}
    \begin{tblr}{%
 hline{1} = {2-Y}{2.5pt}, hline{2} = {2-Y}{1.5pt},   hline{3} = {1-Z}{2pt}, hline{4-7} = {1-Y}{solid},   hline{8} = {1-Z}{1.5pt}, hline{9-12} = {1-Y}{solid},  hline{13} = {1-Z}{1.5pt}, hline{14-17} = {1-Z}{solid},    hline{18} = {1-Z}{1.5pt}, hline{19-22} = {1-Z}{solid},    hline{23} = {1-Z}{2.5pt}, %   hline{even [3-Z]} = {solid, gray!30}, hline{2-Z} = {1.5pt},
    vline{1} = {3-Z}{2.5pt}, vline{2} = {1-Z}{2pt}, vline{3-4} = {2-Z}{solid}, vline{5} = {1-Z}{1.5pt}, vline{6-7} = {2-Z}{solid}, vline{8} = {1-Z}{1.5pt}, vline{9-10} = {2-Z}{solid}, vline{11} = {1-Z}{2pt}, vline{12} = {3-Z}{2.5pt},% vline{23} = {3-Z}{1.5pt},% vline{Z} = {3-Z}{1.5pt}, vline{2-Y}={1.5pt},
    colsep=2.5pt, colspec={r *{12}{X[c]} c}, cell{1}{2-Y}={bg=gray!80}, cell{3-Z}{Z}={bg=lightgray, cmd=\rotcell[cc]},  cell{2}{2-Y}={bg=gray!30,font=\bfseries}, vspan=even
    }
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c} SSS &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} RRR &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} TTT Length &&& \\
    \SetCell[r=1]{c,$} & 
    $\symbf{\vartheta = 0.8}$ & $\symbf{\vartheta = 0.9}$ & $\symbf{\vartheta = .95}$ & 
    $\symbf{\vartheta = 0.8}$ & $\symbf{\vartheta = 0.9}$ & $\symbf{\vartheta = .95}$ & 
    $\symbf{\vartheta = 0.8}$ & $\symbf{\vartheta = 0.9}$ & $\symbf{\vartheta = .95}$ & \\
    \textbf{MMM} & 1.14 & 1.17 &  1.13 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 & 6 & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\symbf{ss1d=177}$\\
    \textbf{NNN} & 0.09 & 0.11 &  0.12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    \textbf{OOO} & 0.11 & 0.13 &  0.15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 0 & \\
    \textbf{PPP} & 0.09 &19.12 & 17.15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 & 9 & \\
    \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{50.83} & \textbf{40.84} & \textbf{20.65} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{20} & \textbf{23} & \textbf{19} & \\  
    %%%%%
    \textbf{MMM} & 13.41 & 63.51 & 93.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 & 6 & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\symbf{ss1d=31}$\\
    \textbf{NNN} & 33.27 & 93.34 & 30.36 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    \textbf{OOO} & 31.32 & 35.4  & 37.44 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 0 & \\
    \textbf{PPP} & 30.28 & 38.36 & 38.44 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 & 9 & \\
    \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{19.94} & \textbf{27} & \textbf{16.55} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{21} & \textbf{22} & \textbf{17} & \\ 
    %%%%%  
    \textbf{MMM} & 55.69 & 56.84 & 55.63 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 & 6 & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\symbf{ss1d=51}$\\
    \textbf{NNN} & 56.46 & 54.56 & 59.6  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    \textbf{OOO} & 55.54 & 57.66 & 35.73 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 0 & \\
    \textbf{PPP} & 75.47 & 85.6  & 85.73 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 & 9 & \\
    \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{26.97} & \textbf{38} & \textbf{26.52} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{5} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{20} & \\    
    %%%%%
    \textbf{MMM} & 116.37 & 116.68 & 171.26 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 & 6 & \SetCell[r=5]{c,$}$\symbf{ss1d=110}$\\
    \textbf{NNN} & 140.91 & 116.12 & 117.19 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    \textbf{OOO} & 121.08 & 119.32 & 181.45 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 0 & \\
    \textbf{PPP} & 150.94 & 191.2  & 191.47 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 & 9 & \\
    \textbf{QQQ} & \textbf{25.18} & \textbf{53.18} & \textbf{45.93} & 16 & 18 & 0 & \textbf{17} & \textbf{17} & \textbf{17} & \\ 
 
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}

\end{document}


Addendum: The OP specified, inter alia,
colspec={r X[c, font=\normalsize] *{11}{X[c]} c}

for both tables. However, the tables have 11 columns, not 14 columns. Hence, either
colspec={r X[c, font=\normalsize] *{8}{X[c]} c}

or, better yet,
colspec={l *{9}{X[c]} c}

would appear to be (more) correct.
Taking this thought on board, omitting most interior horizontal and vertical rules in order to give the tables a more open and inviting "look", narrowing the widths of all exterior rules from 2pt, 3pt, or even 4pt [yikes!] to just 0.8pt, choosing less-dark grays, and applying some further code streamlining yields the following result.

% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX spellcheck = de_GB
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}

\usepackage[hmargin={2cm,15mm}, vmargin=15mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf, skip=0.25\baselineskip]{caption}
%\usepackage[labelfont=bf,textfont=bf,labelsep=colon]{subcaption} % not needed

\usepackage{setspace,mathtools,amsthm,tikz,
            tocbibind,enumitem,csquotes,microtype,
            nicematrix,rotating,makecell,xcolor}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}      % Times Roman clone
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\usepackage{tabularray}
%\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} % why? you don't seem to be using it...

\begin{document}
 
\begin{table}[p!]
    \footnotesize % <-- new
    \setstretch{0.95} % <-- new
    \captionsetup{font=small} % <-- new
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\boldmath$ss1d=177$}
    
    %% first table
    \caption{MAE values of evaluation for MA(2) models if $n = 25$} 
    \label{tabb32}
    \begin{tblr}{%
    hline{1,2} = {2-Y}{0.8pt},   
    hline{3,8,13,18,23} = {1-Z}{0.8pt}, 
    vline{1,12} = {3-Z}{0.8pt}, 
    vline{2,5,8,11} = {1-Z}{0.8pt},
    colspec={>{\bfseries}l *{9}{X[c]} c}, colsep=3pt, 
    cell{1}{2-Y}={bg=gray!30, font=\bfseries}, 
    cell{2}{2-Y}={bg=gray!15, font=\boldmath}, 
    cell{3-Z}{Z}={bg=gray!30, cmd=\rotcell[cc]}, 
    vspan=even
    }
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c} SSS &&& 
      \SetCell[c=3]{c} RRR &&& 
      \SetCell[c=3]{c} TTT Length &&& \\
    & $\vartheta=0.8$ & $\vartheta=0.9$ & $\vartheta=0.95$  
    & $\vartheta=0.8$ & $\vartheta=0.9$ & $\vartheta=0.95$  
    & $\vartheta=0.8$ & $\vartheta=0.9$ & $\vartheta=0.95$ \\
    MMM & 1.14 &  1.17 &  1.13 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  6 
        & \SetCell[r=5]{c} $\symbf{ss1d=177}$ \\
    NNN & 0.09 &  0.11 &  0.12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    OOO & 0.11 &  0.13 &  0.15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 &  0 & \\
    PPP & 0.09 & 19.12 & 17.15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 &  9 & \\
    QQQ & \textbf{50.83} & \textbf{40.84} & \textbf{20.65} 
        & 0 & 0 & 0 
        & \textbf{20} & \textbf{23} & \textbf{19} & \\  
    %%%%%
    MMM & 13.41 & 63.51 & 93.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  6 
        & \SetCell[r=5]{c} $\symbf{ss1d=31}$ \\
    NNN & 33.27 & 93.34 & 30.36 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    OOO & 31.32 & 35.4  & 37.44 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 &  0 & \\
    PPP & 30.28 & 38.36 & 38.44 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 &  9 & \\
    QQQ & \textbf{19.94} & \textbf{27} & \textbf{16.55} 
        & 0 & 0 & 0 
        & \textbf{21} & \textbf{22} & \textbf{17} & \\ 
    %%%%%  
    MMM & 55.69 & 56.84 & 55.63 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  6 
        & \SetCell[r=5]{c} $\symbf{ss1d=51}$\\
    NNN & 56.46 & 54.56 & 59.6  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    OOO & 55.54 & 57.66 & 35.73 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 &  0 & \\
    PPP & 75.47 & 85.6  & 85.73 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 &  9 & \\
    QQQ & \textbf{26.97} & \textbf{38} & \textbf{26.52} 
        & 0 & 0 & 0 
        & \textbf{5} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{20} & \\    
    %%%%%
    MMM & 116.37 & 116.68 & 171.26 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  6 
        & \SetCell[r=5]{c} $\symbf{ss1d=110}$\\
    NNN & 140.91 & 116.12 & 117.19 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    OOO & 121.08 & 119.32 & 181.45 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 &  0 & \\
    PPP & 150.94 & 191.2  & 191.47 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 &  9 & \\
    QQQ & \textbf{25.18} & \textbf{53.18} & \textbf{45.93} 
        & 16 & 18 & 0 
        & \textbf{17} & \textbf{17} & \textbf{17} & \\ 
 
    \end{tblr}

    \bigskip\bigskip

    %% second table
    \caption{MAE values of evaluation for MA(2) models if $n = 25$} 
    \label{tabb33}
    \begin{tblr}{%
    hline{1,2} = {2-Y}{0.8pt},   
    hline{3,8,13,18,23} = {1-Z}{0.8pt}, 
    vline{1,12} = {3-Z}{0.8pt}, 
    vline{2,5,8,11} = {1-Z}{0.8pt},
    colspec={>{\bfseries}l *{9}{X[c]} c},
    colsep=3pt, 
    cell{1}{2-Y}={bg=gray!30, font=\bfseries}, 
    cell{2}{2-Y}={bg=gray!15, font=\boldmath}, 
    cell{3-Z}{Z}={bg=gray!30, cmd=\rotcell[cc]},  
    vspan=even
    }
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c} SSS &&& 
      \SetCell[c=3]{c} RRR &&& 
      \SetCell[c=3]{c} TTT Length &&& \\
    & $\vartheta=0.8$ & $\vartheta=0.9$ & $\vartheta=0.95$  
    & $\vartheta=0.8$ & $\vartheta=0.9$ & $\vartheta=0.95$  
    & $\vartheta=0.8$ & $\vartheta=0.9$ & $\vartheta=0.95$ \\
    MMM & 1.14 & 1.17 &  1.13 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  6 
        & \SetCell[r=5]{c} $\symbf{ss1d = 177}$\\
    NNN & 0.09 & 0.11 &  0.12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    OOO & 0.11 & 0.13 &  0.15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 &  0 & \\
    PPP & 0.09 &19.12 & 17.15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 &  9 & \\
    QQQ & \textbf{50.83} & \textbf{40.84} & \textbf{20.65} 
        & 0 & 0 & 0 
        & \textbf{20} & \textbf{23} & \textbf{19} & \\  
    %%%%%
    MMM & 13.41 & 63.51 & 93.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  6 
        & \SetCell[r=5]{c} $\symbf{ss1d=31}$\\
    NNN & 33.27 & 93.34 & 30.36 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    OOO & 31.32 & 35.4  & 37.44 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 &  0 & \\
    PPP & 30.28 & 38.36 & 38.44 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 &  9 & \\
    QQQ & \textbf{19.94} & \textbf{27} & \textbf{16.55} 
        & 0 & 0 & 0 
        & \textbf{21} & \textbf{22} & \textbf{17} & \\ 
    %%%%%  
    MMM & 55.69 & 56.84 & 55.63 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  6 
        & \SetCell[r=5]{c} $\symbf{ss1d=51}$\\
    NNN & 56.46 & 54.56 & 59.6  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    OOO & 55.54 & 57.66 & 35.73 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 &  0 & \\
    PPP & 75.47 & 85.6  & 85.73 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 &  9 & \\
    QQQ & \textbf{26.97} & \textbf{38} & \textbf{26.52} 
        & 0 & 0 & 0 
        & \textbf{5} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{20} & \\    
    %%%%%
    MMM & 116.37 & 116.68 & 171.26 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  6 
        & \SetCell[r=5]{c} $\symbf{ss1d=110}$\\
    NNN & 140.91 & 116.12 & 117.19 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
    OOO & 121.08 & 119.32 & 181.45 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 &  0 & \\
    PPP & 150.94 & 191.2  & 191.47 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 &  9 & \\
    QQQ & \textbf{25.18} & \textbf{53.18} & \textbf{45.93} 
        & 16 & 18 & 0 
        & \textbf{17} & \textbf{17} & \textbf{17} & \\ 
 
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}

\end{document}


Edit:
COnsidered are @Mico comments
As supplement to nice @Mico answer (+1). Main differences are:

styles for both tables are merged in one definition in \SetTblrInner
both tables are  in one table float
increased are font size in table (to \small)
reduced are thickness of table lines, to my opinion thickness of the 1pt is much nicer

% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = de_GB
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[hmargin={2cm,15mm},vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,tikz,tocbibind,enumitem}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS} % Times Roman clone
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\usepackage{csquotes,microtype,nicematrix,rotating,makecell,xcolor}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont=bf,
            skip=0.25\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{\footnotesize\itshape}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
\small
\SetTblrInner{%
        rowsep = 0.5pt,
        hline{1,2} = {2-Y}{1pt},
        hline{3,8,13,18,23,28,33,38,Z} = {1-Z}{1pt},
        vline{1,Z} = {3-Z}{1pt},
        vline{2,5,8,11} = {1-Z}{1pt},
        cell{1}{2,5,8}={c=3}{bg=lightgray},
        row{1}  = {abovesep=1pt, belowsep=0pt},
        cell{3-Z}{Z}={bg=lightgray},
        cell{7,12,17,22}{2-4,8-10} = {font=\bfseries},
        colsep = 2.2pt,
        row{2} = {mode=math, cmd=\symbf},
        vspan  = even,
                        }

\caption{MAE Values of Evaluation for MA(2) Models if $n = 25$},
  \label{tabb31}  
  \begin{tblr}{colspec = {    Q[l, font=\bfseries]
                          *{9}{X[c]}
                               Q[c, m, font=\bfseries,
                                    cmd=\settowidth\rotheadsize{$ss1d=10$}\rothead]
                           },
              }
%%%%
    &   SSS &&& RRR &&& TTT Length &&&  \\
    & {\vartheta = 0.8} & {\vartheta = 0.9} & {\vartheta = 0.95}
    & {\vartheta = 0.8} & {\vartheta = 0.9} & {\vartheta = 0.95}
    & {\vartheta = 0.8} & {\vartheta = 0.9} & {\vartheta = 0.95}
    &   \\
MMM &  1.14 &  1.17 &  1.13 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  6  &   \SetCell[r=5]{} {ss1d=177}  \\
NNN &  0.09 &  0.11 &  0.12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14  &   \\
OOO &  0.11 &  0.13 &  0.15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 &  0  &   \\
PPP &  0.09 & 19.12 & 17.15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 &  9  &   \\
QQQ & 50.83 & 40.84 & 20.65 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 20 & 23 & 19  &   \\
    %%%%%
MMM & 13.41 & 63.51 & 93.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  6  &   \SetCell[r=5]{} {ss1d=31}  \\
NNN & 33.27 & 93.34 & 30.36 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14  &   \\
OOO & 31.32 & 35.4  & 37.44 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 &  0  &   \\
PPP & 30.28 & 38.36 & 38.44 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 &  9  &   \\
QQQ & 19.94 & 27    & 16.55 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 21 & 22 & 17  &   \\
    %%%%%
MMM & 55.69 & 56.84 & 55.63 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  6  &   \SetCell[r=5]{} {ss1d=51}\\
NNN & 56.46 & 54.56 & 59.6  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14  &   \\
OOO & 55.54 & 57.66 & 35.73 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 &  0  &   \\
PPP & 75.47 & 85.6  & 85.73 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 &  9  &   \\
QQQ & 26.97 & 38    & 26.52 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  5 &  5 & 20  &   \\
    %%%%%
MMM & 116.37 & 116.68 &171.26 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  6 &  \SetCell[r=5]{} {ss1d=110}\\
NNN & 140.91 & 116.12 &117.19 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 &  \\
OOO & 121.08 & 119.32 &181.45 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 &  0 &  \\
PPP & 150.94 & 191.2  &191.47 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 &  9 &  \\
QQQ & 25.18  & 53.18  & 45.93 &16 &18 & 0 & 17 & 17 & 17 &  \\
    \end{tblr}


    %%%% second table
\bigskip
\caption{MAE Values of Evaluation for MA(2) Models if $n = 25$}
  \label{tabb32}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {     Q[l, font=\bfseries]
                            *{9}{X[c]}
                                 Q[c, m, font=\bfseries,
                                   cmd=\settowidth\rotheadsize{$ss1d=10$}\rothead]
                            },
                 }
%%%%
    &   SSS &&& RRR &&& TTT Length &&&  \\
    & {\vartheta = 0.8} & {\vartheta = 0.9} & {\vartheta = 0.95}
    & {\vartheta = 0.8} & {\vartheta = 0.9} & {\vartheta = 0.95}
    & {\vartheta = 0.8} & {\vartheta = 0.9} & {\vartheta = 0.95}
    &   \\
MMM & 1.14 & 1.17 &  1.13 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  6 &  \SetCell[r=5]{} {ss1d=177}\\
NNN & 0.09 & 0.11 &  0.12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 &  \\
OOO & 0.11 & 0.13 &  0.15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 &  0 &  \\
PPP & 0.09 &19.12 & 17.15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 &  9 &  \\
QQQ & 50.83&40.84 & 20.65 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 20 & 23 & 19 &  \\
    %%%%%
MMM &13.41 &63.51 & 93.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  6 &  \SetCell[r=5]{} {ss1d=31}\\
NNN &33.27 &93.34 & 30.36 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 &  \\
OOO &31.32 &35.4  & 37.44 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 &  0 &  \\
PPP &30.28 &38.36 & 38.44 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 &  9 &  \\
QQQ &19.94 &27    & 16.55 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 21 & 22 & 17 &  \\
    %%%%%
MMM &55.69 &56.84 & 55.63 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  6 &  \SetCell[r=5]{} {ss1d=51}\\
NNN &56.46 &54.56 & 59.6  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 & 14 &  \\
OOO &55.54 &57.66 & 35.73 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18 & 18 &  0 &  \\
PPP &75.47 &85.6  & 85.73 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 10 &  9 &  \\
QQQ &26.97 &38    & 26.52 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  5 &  5 & 20 &  \\
    %%%%%
MMM  &116.37 &116.68 & 171.26 & 0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  6 & \SetCell[r=5]{} {ss1d=110}\\
NNN  &140.91 &116.12 & 117.19 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 18 & 18 & 14 & \\
OOO  &121.08 &119.32 & 181.45 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 18 & 18 &  0 & \\
PPP  &150.94 &191.2  & 191.47 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 10 & 10 &  9 & \\
QQQ  & 25.18 & 53.18 &  45.93 &16 &18 &  0 & 17 & 17 & 17 & \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}



Are you sure it’s permissible to merge the two tables into one? While the OP provided two identical tables as sample code, that’s probably not representative of the real tables they need to typeset.

@Mico, now I'm not sure. I will try to split table asap.

@Mico, table is now split to two tables

@Mico, in this particular case, since tables hasn't  table notes, is preferable to use just tblr . In rush I didn't change this. I will  correct this that OP will not be confused.

Thanks. +1 :-) I might also be tempted to replace \begin{table}[htp] with \begin{table}[p] since the tables are supposed to reside together on a single page.

@Mico, I edit my answer again and consider all yours comments. Thank you very much for them.
